# Using scope resolution operator to define mutiple class member function

Tags: c++, scope-resolution-operator

Just for convenience, is there a way to turn this

```
class foo{
  public:
    void fun1();
    void fun2();
}

void foo::fun1(){
  //something
}

void foo::fun2(){
  //something
}
```

into something like this? (I know the code is invalid)

```
class foo{
  public:
    void fun1();
    void fun2();
}

foo::{
  void fun1(){
    //something
  }
  void fun1(){
    //something
  }
}
```

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Nope. You can define the functions inside the class definition though if you want.

Comment: But it'd be nice to have a namespace-like syntax for implementing member functions. I kind of like the syntax in this question.

Comment: The good news is the answer is **YES**, there is a way to do that!  The bad news is it involves making your own programming language.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's a short answer, but not far from a complete answer :) Maybe you'd like to write one up.

Comment: @cigien Yeah, it's just I'd like to offer a work around, but I can't think of anything that wouldn't hurt compile time or refactoring.

Comment: @NathanOliver Fair enough. "No, it's not possible" does feel incomplete, even if correct.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need this?

Comment: I mean, the closest thing I can think of is to implement the methods inline, but I wouldn't do that.